# GRUB is absent after re-installing Windows XP

Tags: 12.04, grub2, bootloader

I formatted my XP drive and installed XP again, and now I can't boot into Ubuntu. I just need the option of selecting Ubuntu while the system boots.

Thanks in advance for replies.

Comment: Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair to reinstall grub bootloader

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu; did you install without restarting your PC or installed it after restarting and selecting your boot device at boot-up?

Comment: Windows cannot detect Linux distros, this is why it is recommended to usually install Windows, then install Ubuntu. Check this answer [here on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/8698)

Answer (score 1):

Windows will do that: It assumes its the only OS and overwrites the Master Boot Record (MBR).   It's usually easier to install Windows first.  Fortunately its not difficult to fix.  Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

The easiest way is

- Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
- Install and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
- Click "Recommended Repair".
- Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers:

1) The easy answer is just reinstall Ubuntu. Backup the data of your Linux partition onto a thumb drive and "nuke and pave" that is to say format and install right over top of the old Linux.

2) A bit more tricky. You'll want to install a Linux boot option into your boot.ini file in windows. See [here](http://bkpavan.wordpress.com/2008/04/02/how-to-boot-linux-using-windows-bootloader-xp/) for details.

Good luck!